# Associative array change key values

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following code to iterate through json array and change the value in the array.

```
<?php
$json='[{"type":"dropdown","label":"Is the property tenanted ?","req":0,"choices":[{"label":"Yes","sel":0,"notification":0,"subOptions":[{"NoteLabel":"Real Estate Agency ?","NoteValue":"","reqNote":"1"},{"NoteLabel":"Agents Mobile Number:","NoteValue":"","reqNote":"1"},{"NoteLabel":"Agents Email:","NoteValue":"","reqNote":"0"},{"PhotoLabel":"Attach a photo","PhotoValues":"","reqPhoto":"1"},{"NoteLabel":"Tenants Contact Number:","NoteValue":"","reqNote":"0"}]},{"label":"No","sel":1,"notification":0,"subOptions":[{"NoteLabel":"Clients Contact Number:","NoteValue":"","reqNote":"1"},{"PhotoLabel":"Attach a photo","PhotoValues":"","reqPhoto":"1"}]},{"label":"N\/A","sel":0,"notification":0,"subOptions":[]}]}]';
echo $json."<br/>";
echo "<br/><br/><br/>****************<br/><br/><br/>";
$json=json_decode($json,true);
foreach($json as $kSub => $vSub)
{
    if( in_array($vSub['type'], ["dropdown"]))
    {
         if($vSub['label']=="Is the property tenanted ?")
         {
               $choices=&$vSub['choices'];
               foreach($choices as $keyChoice=>&$valChoice)
               {
                   if($valChoice['label']=="Yes")
                   {
                       $subOptions=&$valChoice['subOptions'];
                       foreach($subOptions as $kop=>&$Opval)
                       {
                           foreach($Opval as $kn=>&$vn)
                           {
                               if($kn=="NoteLabel")
                               {

                                    if($vn=="Real Estate Agency ?")
                                    { 

                                        $subOptions[$kop]['NoteValue']="DOMAIN";
                                    }
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
         }
    }
}

echo json_encode($json)."<br/>";
```

I want to change the `NoteValue` inside `subOptions` array if the conditions are met. I am not sure whether I am doing it right or not, but the value is not changing. Please help me to sort out what I am doing wrong! I was also wondering whether I can reduce the number of code lines to get the result?

Comment: You need to use a reference variable for `$vSub`, just like in all the other loops.

Comment: Ah..thank you very much. Saved my day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `&vSub` to make it a reference variable.

You can shorten the code by getting rid of the last loop, and just access the `NoteLabel` index directly. You can also combine the first two tests with `&&`. And you don't need any of the index variables in your `foreach` loops.

```
foreach($json as &$vSub)
{
    if($vSub['type'] == "dropdown" && $vSub['label']=="Is the property tenanted ?")
    {
        $choices=&$vSub['choices'];
        foreach($choices as &$valChoice)
        {
            if($valChoice['label']=="Yes")
            {
                $subOptions=&$valChoice['subOptions'];
                foreach($subOptions as &$Opval)
                {
                    if (isset($Opval['NoteLabel']) && $Opval['NoteLabel'] == "Real Estate Agency ?") 
                    {
                        $Opval['NoteValue']="DOMAIN";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try this code, I get Undefined index: NoteLabel Notice as well as I have PhotoLabel array in the subOption array

Comment: I added an `isset()` check to make sure the key exists.